# Chemical Mechanism Behind Water-Soluble Ink

Tags: water, polymers

I came across water-soluble ink pens designed for creating temporary fabric marks, particularly in cross-stitch stamping. These ink dissolve in water, transforming water into a colorful liquid, while ensuring the fabric remains clean without any stains.

I'm interested in understanding the inner workings of these ink and their chemical composition. How does this type of ink function, and what specific chemical components enable it to dissolve in water without leaving stains on the fabric?

I appreciate any insights into the science behind these ink pens. Thank you

[image]

Comment: These are proprietary water soluble dyes. Only the company will know the exact composition. Search water soluble dyes. It must be a huge class of dyes which polar functional groups.

Comment: BTW, some dyes adhere to cotton and linen (cellulose-based fibers), others to wool and silk (protein-based), etc. Those inks might wash off one fabric, and not another.